# Why did mango lose sweetness after pureeing

Tags: puree

It is mango season and I am pureeing Mangoes. I used Malgoa mangoes which have a very sweet taste. The mango pieces taste sweeter than the puree. The puree is still sweet, but less. Why is that?

Comment: How are you pureeing? It might be that if you are incorporating air into the mix that that would dilute the intensity, or if you are cooking it you may not be reducing the mixture sufficiently.

Comment: I am pureeing in a blender.